# Remember Jquery click event target id

Tags: jquery

when I use on event of jquery, for example,

```
$(document).on('click', '.cell_thumbnails', function(e){

    selected = e.currentTarget.id;

});
```

Where selected is a global variable, now every time the click event happens, the selected will be updated, I am wondering how I can store the previous target id?

Answer (score 1):

Push the IDs into an array:

```
var ids = [];

$(document).on('click', '.cell_thumbnails', function(e){
    selected = e.currentTarget.id;
    ids.push(selected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same thing but with a `var prevSelected` :

```
$(document).on('click', '.cell_thumbnails', function(e){

    prevSelected = selected;
    selected = e.currentTarget.id;

});
```